# function to fire on button

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have button  with `id = btnadd` And java script file “myscript” which is referenced in layout page.

I want this function to fire on button click but this doesn’t happen. Could anybody tell me what  is the error here?

View script like this:
[image]

myscript java script file like this:
[image]

Comment: Your code needs to be in the question (not links to images)

Comment: [How to post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnaddd", function() {
    alert("click");
});
```

If it still does not work then you might have used the same ID btnadd for two different elements and JQUERY only matches the first one.

Comment: Use that code instead of *what*?  The OP didn't bother to include code in the question, and you aren't helping them or others in the future by providing a vague answer with a guess.

Comment: He is a new user and was properly corrected by Stephen Muecke so he is probably gonna edit/fix his post. That's why I answered since the two causes for this is either the element was not there when the listener was registered or the problem of having two elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe multiple elementes with de same id, you can see this code at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bm2esp2p).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mybt').click(function(){
    alert('s')
  })
});
```